# Can there be war between male(humans) and female(humans) in distant future?

Tags: human-nature

It's been a long time since I have been thinking this and haven't found answers but I do have some viewpoints. First of all let me describe the problem. We know that humans are the only species on earth to have the power of science and maths(knowledge) with them. Now this includes two versions of same species and those are male(humans) and female(humans).Now we all know that science and maths has been rapidly developing and is developing rapidly. Now as developments in science happen, we might(surely would) see a future where science has developed so much that there is no need for male-female interaction for birth of new babies and I think that probably in future, not many would love to marry or in other words, humans would create their offsprings with the help of science rather than coupling. Now once this is clarified, let's proceed to next point. Next point is that males and females till now have got along very well without any big conflict and the main reason goes to their interdependency for continued existence of both but once this interdependency breaks, would males and females see each other as competitors rather than partners? And would this cause a big war in future where one of the species would emerge as final winner?

Now I have been thinking long on this and there are certainly other ways this all could end and that is that with the help of science, males and females may combine to for single species and that is definitely super science fiction.

Comment: This may be a better fit on [worldbuilding.se].

Answer (score 2):

Dystopias of humanity splitting into two hostile, biologically distinct groups are common in science fiction (Eloi and Morlocks in “The Time Machine” by H. G. Wells). And the idea of a war between men and women is common in mythology (“The Maidens' War” in Bohemian folk tradition).

In Ancient Greek mythology, there was an all-male counterpart to the Amazons, the Gargareans. Both “tribes” were dependent on each other for reproduction and annually met for that purpose. The boys born by the Amazons were given to the Gargareans, the girls stayed with their mothers.

It is very likely that in the (not even so distant) future, humans will reach *total* reproductive independence from the other gender (artificial sperm, artificial eggs/wombs).

Now there is of course heterosexual or -romantic attraction between men and women. But for this some sort of surrogate might perhaps be invented?

So is a war between men and women possible in the distant future? Yes, yes. Of course it is **POSSIBLE.** This scenario cannot be refuted. Already in 1967 radical feminist Valerie Solanas went so far to propose [the extermination of men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCUM_Manifesto) (it is debated if this was satire).

But possibility is a very low bar. Is it plausible? I’d say no. Even if we *can* make men or women redundant for the continuation of the human species and for our emotional fulfillment, the costs of an artificial replacement seem to be quite considerable. And unnecessary, considering that natural men and women abound on this planet.

There also is no reason for a conflict between men and women. Both genders are human and *can* peacefully coexist. It’s not like vampires and humans where the conflict would be strictly unavoidable. Or even humans and wild animals (that suffer from habitat loss by agriculture, urbanization, etc.).

Comment: The cost you argue is not fixed for anything. Reaching Mars would have costed billions but now it costs millions. Similarly cost for artificial reproduction can certainly become super cheap. Now your second idea that males and females can coexist, well no, even two males can't coexist together and the reason being that two individuals push for their own gains. Even today's, countries exists which is the idea of how even today human species are divided within themselves

Comment: @Ritanshu It seems you conflate the ability to coexist with the absence of any potential for conflict. As any honest woman will tell you, conflicts between women tend to be much more frequent, fierce, harsh, and personal than conflicts with men are. Does that mean they kill each other or men all the time? Hardly.

Comment: @Ritanshu I meant large-scale, deadly, existential conflict here. OFC there is radical feminism, everyday misogyny, men’s rights, lesbian separatism, machismo, “bros before hoes”, MGTOW, … But though the biological differences between the sexes are obvious (different organs!), intra-sex loyalty is **rather** low. E. g. there are loads of female suicide bombers in Nigeria. They blow themselves up to kill “kafir” for Boko Haram (pushing an extremely patriarchal Islam). So religion/ideology trumps intra-sex loyality (a western woman is considered the enemy); and the same is true for men.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing about domestic slavery is that many people equate skill at making money with intelligence.

I suppose my wife is a very, very good cook.

Comment: sorry for the facetious comment, please don't down vote I will lose...